# JS doesn't read imported and declared variables into console.log

Tags: javascript, variables, visual-studio-code

I am following Jonas Schmedtmann's JS course.

So, after setting up babel, npm, webpack etc. we made a `test.js` file which would export its data into an `index.js` file (as seen on the screenshots).

However, when I test this - the `console.log()` is unchanged and does not include the variables that should? be displayed.

**EVEN THO** `const x` is declared within the same file! It's not even exported or imported.

PS. I get errors on both import and const saying "x" or "xxx" *is declared, but its value is never read. ts(6133).* It gives me a quick fix option which deletes both const and import. Very funny.

[image]

Comment: Please use backticks (`) and not a single quote

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using single quotes ('') instead of backticks (``).  If you would like to use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) then you must use backticks instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

you should use backtick symbol (`)  symbol instead of single quotes (')

This is a feature called template literals.
for more details see documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

For an example:

```
console.log(`Hi i am ${name}`)   //this is correct statement

console.log('Hi i am ${name}')    // this is wrong
```

Answer (score -1):

Either use backticks for template strings or concat the strings or use `console.log`'s varargs call-style:

```js
const xxx = require("./test");
console.log(`xxx = ${xxx}`);
console.log('xxx = ', xxx);
console.log('xxx = ' + xxx);
```